# PIC18 IO-Port noobie issues with XC8

Tags: pic, mplab, xc8

I'm comming from many years on AVR and starting my first PIC project with a PIC18F46K42.
Using actual MPLAB v5.15 with XC8 compiler v2.05 (set to C99 standard).
(signing up at the microchip forum doesn't work for days...)

And now I'm having basic problems to get a simple IO-port access working:

First setting RC6 as Output:

```
TRISC = 0b10111111;
```

Now trying to read IO-Port RC6:

```
uint8_t LEDstate = PORTCbits_t.RC6; // auto completition of PORTC.. command by xc8
```

=> compiling Error: unexpected type name 'PORTCbits_t': expected expression

The command "PORTCbits.RC6, without "_t" , which is published in many tutorials, isn't recognized by the compiler at all

And then trying to write to IO-Port RC6:

```
LATCbits_t.LATC6 = 0; // auto completition of LATC.. command by xc8
```

=> compinling Error: expected identifier or '('

The command "LATCbits.LATC6, without "_t" , which is also published in many tutorials, isn't also recognized by the compiler at all

Reading the xc8 manual and the datasheet doesn't really help...
I think, I missed something basic with this  IDE / compiler. Maybe within the setup...

Any ides or suggestions of documentation are really appreciated!!

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using MCC (MPLAB Code Configurator). It will make things easier for using the peripherals - even just simple pin I/O.

It also makes keeping track of your resources easier.

You can create alias names for the pins and then MCC will provide you with clean macros like:

```
#define LEDState_SetHigh()            do { LATCbits.LATC6 = 1; } while(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`..._t` is wrong, it's a type definition. Take a look at the part header (pic18lf46k42.h), line 46579. The actual port structure, defined at the next line, is called `PORTCbits` . In order for this name to be recognized you need to `#include <xc.h>` in your source and make sure the correct part is set up in the MPLAB project.

I'm using this notation all the time and it always works, given that the pin exists and the above two conditions are met. Example:

https://github.com/felis/stirrer/blob/f-desk/board_control/code/stirrer/bsp.h#L58

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Oleg, the ..._t is incorrect. Change the line to the one below and it will compile without issues.

```
uint8_t LEDstate = PORTCbits.RC6; // auto completition of PORTC.. command by xc8
```

I've just tried the following code with your chip and it compiled without any issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    uint8_t LEDstate = PORTCbits.RC6; // auto completition of PORTC.. command by xc8
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```